# Find numerical values in a string, perform arithmetic on the all numbers in the string, and output a new, revised string containing new values Java

Tags: java, string, integer, string-math

I need to perform arithmetic operations on numbers in a string.  I understand that I'll need to parse those numbers out, convert to int, do the math, and then convert back to String.

Example:

n = 2.

Input data: "The building is 350 feet tall with a perimeter of 400 feet".

Output data:  The building is 352 feet tall with a perimeter of 402 feet".

I got my for loop iterating through the string and I can affect the value of the number, but I'm having difficulty putting it back into a new, modified string.

Here's where I'm at right now but it's not working

> ```
> String output = new String();
> String tempString = new String();
> int newNumb = 0;
> int n = 2;
> for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++){
>    Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile('-?\\d+');
>    Matcher matcher = integerPattern.matcher(output);
>    newNumb = (Integer.parse(output) + n);
>    tempString = output.replace(output, String.valueOf(newNumb));
> ```

Comment: How to do that would depend, in part, on what language you are using.

Comment: Your question is ok but you would need to try your regular expresion first and use some tracing with sysout